# Authenticate Keycloak Users in Firebase (OIDC Provider)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

I am trying to authenticate `JWT token` generated by keycloak provider in `firebase`.

Here is my firebase configuration.

[image]

After that I am following this code where `oidcIdToken` is I am generating from keycloak server.

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc#signing_in_users_directly

> "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Malformed response cannot be parsed from
> https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/REALM_NAME/.well-known/openid-configuration
> for OIDC_DISCOVERY"

I am creating users in keycloak manually right now also I am new in firebase so I am not sure this is correct way to integerate keycloak in firebase using OIDC configuration.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that Firebase (I guess it is hosted on Google servers) is able to reach your local machine `localhost` where your local Keycloak is running (`https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/REALM_NAME/.well-known/openid-configuration`)? It's very unlikely. Try to expose your Keycloak on public infrastructure and try it again with public Keycloak URL, not localhost one.

Comment: @JanGaraj I am developing front end and configured nuxt application in local.. I have hosted keyclok on cloud too but getting same error